# Why doesn't the escape key close the find window in Chrome?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome

For some reason, Chrome will no longer close my find window when I hit the <kbd>Escape ⎋</kbd> key. Instead, it pulls up some weird kind of autocomplete drop-down. This is incredibly annoying; every time I perform a search, I now need to reach for the mouse immediately afterwards. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Installed any Chrome extensions recently?  If you create a new Chrome user does the behavior persist?

Comment: I've tried disabling every extension, and the problem still occurs. I'll try with a new user and report back.

Comment: I agree this is a annoying.  If you ^F to find something, you are left with orange and yellow highlights all over your screen.  To make these go away, you have to ^F again to bring focus to the find box, then press ESC.

Comment: Are you focused within the find box?  IIRC it never closed with esc unless it had focus